# Laravel: is it possible to store objects in a database field? If so, how?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Suppose I have an `User`, and a `Transaction` model on Laravel. It doesn't matter the properties, they only have in common an `uuid` and a `name` field

Now I want to create an `Audit` model which will take more or less the following fields:

```
id       - The regular autoincrement id
ts       - The timestamp when the action is performed
actor    - The one who performs an action, its a reference to a user's id
verb     - Which action is performing over a certain object
object   - The object to which the action is performed
comment  - whatever
```

So if an admin creates o updates a new user will produce an audit records like

```
1, 1/1/2021 00:00:01, 1, 'create', User, 'bla bla bla'
2, 1/1/2021 00:00:02, 1, 'update', User, 'reset password'
```

But that will also apply to other kind of records like the `Transaction` I mentioned before

Currently I'm storing the object's id, and based on the "verb" (or action), I know the kind of Object they were acting upon, and it works, but I'm experimenting if there are some other ways. My databases aren't huge, so performance is not an issue.

Comment: There is a json column type, you can store the object as json and then later retrieve and extract its fields.

Comment: Could also look into https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Yep, sounds like a Polymorphic Relationship

Comment: Another new thing to me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store an object like that in a database is in a [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

I'd suggest creating a new [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations) and [model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models) for your audit, and storing all the relevant information there.

However, you can serialize your object as a string if you don't have any performance concerns, or if the data structure is likely to change. A popular way of doing this is to use `json_encode($your_obj)`.